# How to generate list of files compiled from GNU make incremental build?

Tags: gnu-make

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

Every time **make** is called, inside my Makefile I have a call to a script which runs a lint tool. However I want to avoid telling lint to search the entire code base again, instead it should only run against the files that make did an incremental build. If the file was not re-compiled, there is no need to run lint on it again.

I don't know how **make** checks which files need to be re-compiled on incremental builds. I don't think that is stored as a list anywhere either.

If I don't want to wrap **make** with script that logs its output and then later analyses its stdout to see which files have been re-compiled, is there any other way to get this incremental build list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me why you only want to run lint on the files that were out of date on this invocation of make.  What if you run make 5 times and only during the fifth you re-run the lint tool... then you'd just lint the files that were modified during the fifth run of make but you wouldn't lint the files modified during the first four runs.

It seems to me like you really want to run lint on all the files that have been modified since the last time you ran lint.  This is trivial to do:

```
run-lint: $(SOURCES)
        lint $?
        @touch $@
```

The `$?` [automatic variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) expands to just the files that are newer than the target file, then after the lint is complete we touch the target file so it's now up to date.  Every time you run `make run-lint` it will lint all the files that have changed since the last time you ran it.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe it wasn't clear from my question, but that's exactly what I wanted (run lint only for the delta from the last time it ran). This solution works as intended.